# error: cannot find symbol class BR

Tags: android, dagger-2

I'm facing an issue while assembling a library project. I had built an application project & later on converted it to library. I'm not able to generate .aar package. I found few answers here that tells to change the **apt neenbedankt plugin**, attaching **databinding:compiler**, but that didn't worked for me at all. Some might say that dagger is the issue but i'm not sure of it. Please help.

- Here is my error log while assembling a build

  ```
  Information:Gradle tasks [assemble]
  /home/***/***/**/**/productlisting/viewmodel/ProductListFragmentViewModel.java
  Error:(9, 52) error: cannot find symbol class BR
  /home/***/***/**/**/home/viewmodel/NavSubItemViewModel.java
  Error:(3, 52) error: cannot find symbol class BR
  /home/***/***/**/**/productlisting/viewmodel/NavSubItemViewModel.java
  Error:(3, 52) error: cannot find symbol class BR
  /home/***/***/**/**/home/topbrands/BrandActivityViewModel.java
  Error:(3, 52) error: cannot find symbol class BR
  /home/***/***/**/**/productlisting/viewmodel/ProductListActivityViewModel.java
  Error:(3, 52) error: cannot find symbol class BR
  /home/***/***/**/**/home/viewmodel/NewArrivalViewModel.java
  Error:(3, 52) error: cannot find symbol class BR
  /home/***/***/**/**/home/viewmodel/NavParentItemViewModel.java
  Error:(3, 52) error: cannot find symbol class BR
  /home/***/***/**/**/productlisting/viewmodel/NavParentItemViewModel.java
  Error:(3, 52) error: cannot find symbol class BR
  Error:Execution failed for task :app:compileLiveDebugJavaWithJavac.
  Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
  Information:BUILD FAILED
  Information:Total time: 6.519 secs
  Information:9 errors
  Information:0 warnings
  Information:See complete output in console
  ```

  - Here is my module level **`build.gradle`**

``

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'  def gitSha = 'git rev-parse --short HEAD'.execute([],    project.rootDir).text.trim()
android {
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"

defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 1
    versionName getCurrentVersion()
    vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    manifestPlaceholders = [hostNameDeepLink: "http://***.**.in:203/api/"]
    buildConfigField "String", "CodeRevision", "\"{$gitSha}\""
    multiDexEnabled true
    renderscriptTargetApi 19
    renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true

}
testOptions {
    unitTests.returnDefaultValues = true
}
packagingOptions {
    pickFirst 'META-INF/rxjava.properties'
}

signingConfigs {
    planet {
        storeFile file('../****.jks')
        storePassword '***@123'
        keyAlias '***'
        keyPassword '***@123'
    }
}
dataBinding {
    enabled = true
}
lintOptions {
    disable 'InvalidPackage'
    abortOnError false
}
dexOptions {
    jumboMode true
}
productFlavors {
    local {
        String WebServiceUrl = getWebServiceUrl()
        String WebSitePath = getWebSitePath()
        String ImageUrl = getImageUrl()
        String ServerName = getServerName()
        String TestCustomerId = getWebSitePath()
        buildConfigField "String", "WebServiceUrl", "\"$WebServiceUrl\""
        buildConfigField "String", "WebSitePath", "\"$WebSitePath\""
        buildConfigField "String", "ImageUrl", "\"$ImageUrl\""
        buildConfigField "String", "ServerName", "\"$ServerName\""
        buildConfigField "String", "TestCustomerId", "\"$TestCustomerId\""
        manifestPlaceholders = [hostNameDeepLink: "http://10.160.0.18"]
    }
    live {
        String WebServiceUrl = getWebServiceUrl()
        String WebSitePath = getWebSitePath()
        String ImageUrl = getImageUrl()
        String ServerName = getServerName()
        String TestCustomerId = getWebSitePath()
        buildConfigField "String", "WebServiceUrl", "\"$WebServiceUrl\""
        buildConfigField "String", "WebSitePath", "\"$WebSitePath\""
        buildConfigField "String", "ImageUrl", "\"$ImageUrl\""
        buildConfigField "String", "ServerName", "\"$ServerName\""
        buildConfigField "String", "TestCustomerId", "\"$TestCustomerId\""
        /*buildConfigField "String", "WebServiceUrl", "\"http://perfectmother.zoomi.in:203/api/\""
        buildConfigField "String", "WebSitePath", "\"http://perfectmother.zoomi.in:203/\""
        buildConfigField "String", "ImageUrl", "\"http://perfectmother.zoomi.in:203\""
        buildConfigField "String", "ServerName", "\"-Live\""
        buildConfigField "String", "TestCustomerId", "\"10086\""*/
        manifestPlaceholders = [hostNameDeepLink: "http://perfectmother.zoomi.in"]

    }
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        signingConfig signingConfigs.planet
        shrinkResources true
        minifyEnabled true
        zipAlignEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        debuggable false
    }
    debug {
        signingConfig signingConfigs.planet
        debuggable true
        minifyEnabled false
        shrinkResources false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro', 'proguard-rules-debug.pro'
    }
}
}

def static getCurrentVersion() {

def buildEnv = System.getenv("BUILD_NUMBER")

def buildNumber = buildEnv != null ? ".${buildEnv}" : ""

return "1.0" + buildNumber

}

def getWebServiceUrl() {
return hasProperty('WebServiceUrl') ? WebServiceUrl : ''
}

def getWebSitePath() {
    return hasProperty('WebSitePath') ? WebSitePath : ''
}

def getImageUrl() {
    return hasProperty('ImageUrl') ? ImageUrl : ''
}

def getServerName() {
    return hasProperty('ServerName') ? ServerName : ''
}

def getTestCustomerId() {
    return hasProperty('TestCustomerId') ? TestCustomerId : ''
}

ext {
    playServiceVersion = '10.2.1'
    supportLibVersion = '25.3.1'
}
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$supportLibVersion"

// Unit testing
testCompile 'org.robolectric:robolectric-resources:3.0'
testCompile 'org.robolectric:shadows-core:3.2.2'
testCompile 'org.robolectric:robolectric:3.2.2'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
testCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:2.6.3'
//Hamcrest
testCompile 'org.hamcrest:hamcrest-all:1.3'

//Retrofit
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava:2.1.0'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.6.0'

//Zoomi library
compile 'com.zoomi.android:utils:1.0'
compile 'com.zoomi.android:rxutils:1.5.1'

//CardView:
compile "com.android.support:cardview-v7:$supportLibVersion"

//RecyclerView:
compile "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:$supportLibVersion"

//Design
compile "com.android.support:design:$supportLibVersion"

//Glide
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'

//Dagger
compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.9'
annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.9'

//Auto Value
annotationProcessor 'com.google.auto.value:auto-value:1.3'
provided 'com.google.auto.value:auto-value:1.3'

//Auto Value GSON
annotationProcessor 'com.ryanharter.auto.value:auto-value-gson:0.4.6'
provided 'com.ryanharter.auto.value:auto-value-gson:0.4.6'

//Auto Value Parcelable
annotationProcessor 'com.ryanharter.auto.value:auto-value-parcel:0.2.5'
provided 'com.ryanharter.auto.value:auto-value-parcel:0.2.5'

//Rx
compile 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.2.1'
compile 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.1.6'

//Timber
compile 'com.jakewharton.timber:timber:4.3.1'

//FOR CI
compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:$playServiceVersion"

//Fire base crash reporting
compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:$playServiceVersion"

//Fire base authentication
compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:$playServiceVersion"
compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:$playServiceVersion"

//bottom bar
compile 'com.aurelhubert:ahbottomnavigation:2.0.4'

//Groupie
compile 'com.genius:groupie:0.8.0'

//PageIndicator
compile 'com.romandanylyk:pageindicatorview:0.1.1'

//FiftyShadesOf
compile 'com.github.florent37:fiftyshadesof:1.0.0'

//Proguard Snippets
compile 'com.github.PrashamTrivedi:ProguardSnips:0.1-snapshot'

//ProGuard rules for RxJava!
compile 'com.artemzin.rxjava:proguard-rules:1.2.4.0'

//Facebook
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.19.0'

//Twitter
compile('com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter:2.3.1@aar') {
    transitive = true
}

// Crop image
compile 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.3.1'

//Show case
compile 'com.github.deano2390:MaterialShowcaseView:1.1.0'

//GSON
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0'

//Constraint layout
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'

//Firebase cloud messaging
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.2.0'

}

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.22.1'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'http://**.***.**.**:81/release/' }
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: You've somehow posted some HTML rather than your `build.gradle`. Please try a bit harder if you are asking for free help! :-) Please [edit] your question to include the correct `build.gradle` and the full error message

Comment: @DavidRawson - due to multiple single quotes i'm not able to format it properly.

Comment: What happens if you select all, press the tab button for "indent" in Android Studio and then copy paste the `build.gradle` in? I tried editing your question to fix the code dump but it didn't work

Comment: @DavidRawson - thanks for the help, i tried my best to make it correct.

Comment: Have you tried doing a clean/rebuild? Also, you can try `./gradlew --refresh-dependencies`

Comment: it's not working at all, it don't generate BR file & compilation fails.

Comment: I had a look at the `build.gradle` and there's probably too much going on to diagnose the error. You could try running the gradle task with stacktrace/verbose logging enabled but I don't know if it will help.

Try upgrading Dagger 2 and Butterknife and all your annotation processors to the latest version (2.10 for Dagger). Then if that doesn't fix, you can try creating an [mcve] in a new project

Comment: Also, this looks like an app. Why are you moving it to a library project? If slow build times are the issue I doubt this will solve it.

Comment: @DavidRawson - I'm against it but, some shitty managers want it any how to be library project. Let me try upgrading to lattest dagger version

Comment: I hope upgrading fixes your problem. Perhaps you will get a better error message at least with the latest version of Dagger 2. Also, upgrading the build tools version may help. Otherwise it will be a lot of work to find out what is wrong :-(

Comment: @DavidRawson - thanks for your support but it's not working out at all. It seems like code has no effect.

Comment: Did you try the latest version of the build tools as well?

Comment: yes it didn't worked ! :(